# Filling polygons inside other polygons with different hatch symbols

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, matplotlib-basemap

[image: polygon hatch example]

I am trying to figure out how to fill polygons in matplotlib using hatch fills they provide. I plot the polygon objects and fill them with hatches. But as you can see in the image, the hatches cross the boundaries when there is a smaller polygon within a larger one.

Is there any solution such that the smaller polygons within a larger polygon won't be filled with both hatches, but only the hatch I define for the smaller polygon?

My code to plot polygon patches on a map defined by basemap in matplotlib.

```
for index, row in Frame.iterrows():
        polygon_geom, geol_int = row[6], row[7]
        pattern = patterns[int(geol_int)]
        poly_coords = list(polygon_geom.exterior.coords)
        axs1.add_patch(Polygon(poly_coords, closed=True, edgecolor='k',
                          fill=False, hatch=pattern, lw=2.0))
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by using path and pathpatch in matplotlib.